# Stop a python script from executing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below python script(**server.py**) in order to listen to a port and capture the requests from the client. I am calling this script from another python file(**Main.py**). My requirement is to stop executing **server.py** after certain amount of time. I tried using exit() at the last line of the file - **server.py** to stop the server and stop the execution of the file, however I was not able to stop the script from running and the server kept responding. Can anyone help me in letting me know where I am going wrong.

**Server.py**

```
bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 2530

def servercreate():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print('[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d' % (addr[0], addr[1]))
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        client_handler.start()


def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(2056)
    print('[*] Received: %s' % request)

    message = "{}"
    client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    servercreate()
```

**Main.py**

```
import Server
Server.servercreate()
```

Comment: Well, the quick and dirty way is to set [`client_handler.daemon = True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) before `client_handler.start()`. The less forceful method would be to have a `terminate` flag and check that periodically in the client threads.

Comment: Hi @dhke, thanks for the comment. Can you please be a bot more specific as I am new to Python programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want your code interrupted by time.sleep (which I think stops the code from running), use this:

```
import time
timeout = time.time() + 10

while True:
    print ('hello')
    if time.time() > timeout:
        print ('program terminated')
        break
```

if you want 10 minutes worth of time use:

```
timeout = time.time() + 60*10
```

If you just want to stop the program running after a certain amount of time use something like

```
import time

x=0
while True:
    print ('waiting 5')
    time.sleep(5)
    x += 1
    if x == (10):
        break
```

the time.sleep is in seconds, break stops the loop and should end your program

update, try this:

```
import time


bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 2530

def servercreate():

    #put minutes of time you want program to run for below
    minutes = 10
    timeout = time.time() + (60*minutes)

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print('[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d' % (addr[0], addr[1]))
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        client_handler.start()
        if time.time() > timeout:
            break


def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(2056)
    print('[*] Received: %s' % request)

    message = "{}"
    client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    servercreate()
```

Comment: Hi @new_to_coding,  Thanks for the response. I used the first option in my code in the following way. But it did not work.                                                                                                            
        `if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = 0
        while True:
                servercreate()
                time.sleep(5)
                x += 1
                print(x)
                if x == 10:
                    break`

Comment: @Viman I have made an update with a suggestion, try it out and see if it works, change the minutes at the top if you want your program to run for more or less than 10 minutes

Comment: @Viman sorry I saw that I put the time out variable inside the loop, was perhaps meant to be outside of it to avoid continuously setting the timeout variable, so I have edited my answer just in case you need it

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get that yesterday @new_to_coding . But the main logic you gave worked fine.